# Python Magic Method Augmented Assignment misunderstanding

Tags: python, class, methods

I'm creating a simple angle object which is, in it's simplest forms, an integer value that recurs when it goes above 360 (back to 0) or below 0 (back to 360). I implemented the magic methods for augmented assignment and for some reason this isn't working.

```
class Angle:

    def __init__(self, angle):
    self.angle = angle

    def __add__(self, other):
        """Check for recursion, then return the added value."""
        val = self.angle + other
        while val > 360:
            val -= 360
        while val < 0:
            val += 360
        return val

    def __radd__(self, other):
        """Reflected addition."""
        return self.__add__(other)

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        """Augmented addition assignment."""
        val = self.__add__(other)
        self.angle = val
```

It assigns a nonetype value to self.angle,=. It seems to me like it should work, since `self.__add__()` returns the value of other added to self.angle, so why wouldn't it assign `val` to self.angle?

Comment: `return self` from `__iadd__` ?

Comment: What would that do? I thought the augmented assignment magic methods shouldn't return anything?

Comment: Well, it should fix your `__iadd__`

Comment: Could you explain why that works though?

Comment: well, it's not really good, because iadd is more for mutable objects

Comment: Please reconsider your votes.  Note that builtin `int` type does not implement `__iadd__` at all.  There is a good reason why I posted the first comment as a comment and not as an answer, and now I have had time to add a proper answer.

Comment: Note that none of the builtins which model numeric types (`int`, `float`, `complex`...) implement `__iadd__` at all.  This is the data model you should be following in your class!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About `__iadd__` (and other `__iXXX__` methods):

> These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying
>   self) **and return the result** (which could be, but does not have to be,
>   self).

Your `__iadd__` method doesn't "assigns a nonetype to `self.angle`", it returns `None` (default value when a function has no explicit return), and this rebinds your current name to `None`, ie:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, angle=120):
        self.angle = angle

    def __add__(self, other):
        """Check for recursion, then return the added value."""
        print "Foo.add"
        val = self.angle + other
        while val > 360:
            val -= 360
        while val < 0:
            val += 360
        return val


    def __iadd__(self, other):
        """Augmented addition assignment."""
        print "Foo.iadd"
        val = self.__add__(other)
        self.angle = val


f = Foo()
f += 20

print f is None
```

To make a long story short : you want `__iadd__` to return something meaningfull, most probably `self`.

Comment: as an aside, this is true because `x += y` calls `x = x.__iadd__(y)`, so if your `__iadd__` magic method doesn't return a value, it sets `x=None`

Answer (score 1):

Just delete your `__iadd__` method completely.

This will make `+=` operator fall back onto `__add__`, which is the preferred behaviour for objects which model immutable types.

Example:

```
class Angle(int):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val % 360
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Angle(self.val + other)
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Angle(self.val - other)
    def __neg__(self):
        return Angle(-self.val)
    def __repr__(self):
        # just for demonstration purposes ok
        return str(self.val)
```

Let's try it out...

```
>>> a = Angle(35)
>>> a
35
>>> a + 400
75
>>> a
35
>>> a += 400
>>> a
75
>>> a - 75
0
>>> a - 76
359
>>> a
75
>>> a -= 76
>>> a
359
```

No `__iadd__` or `__radd__` is needed, let python handle the magic for you.

Comment: I didn't downvote, in fact I upvoted. The reason I upvoted the others first is simply because you didn't have all this information there before, and I left before I could see that you had provided a well structured, informative comment. Sorry about that! I didn't mean upset you or anyone.

And don't get me wrong, this is a very useful tidbit of info now that you've explained it more in depth and I've had a chance to look at it better, so thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Both `__add__` and `__iadd__` should `return` an `Angle` object:

```
class Angle(object):
    def __init__(self, angle):
        self.angle = angle % 360
    def __add__(self, other):
        return Angle(self.angle + other.angle)
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        return self.__add__(other)
```

Note use of `angle % 360` to keep `angle in range(0, 360)`.

Comment: Oh of course, I never thought of using anlge % 360, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

You need to `return self` from the implementation of `__iadd__` since the return value of `__iadd__` is assigned to the left hand side of the `+=` operator. This is what the Python documentation says about the implementation of in-place operators:

> These methods should attempt to do the operation in-place (modifying self) and return the result (which could be, but does not have to be, self).

([source](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__))