# Python create built-in method for class

Tags: python, class, oop, built-in, arithmetic-expressions

I made a class that can do some fraction arithmetic. I change the built-in method of `__add__`, `__sub__`,`__mul__`,and `__div__` so that it can do arithmetic with fractions. I can use it with the `+`, `-` , `*` , `/` symbols. 
My question is, what do I have to do to be able to use `__iadd__` as `+=`.

```
class Fraction:
    def __init__(self,num,den):
        self.num = num
        self.den = den
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.num)+" / "+str(self.den)

    def __add__(self,other):
        num = self.num * other.den + other.num * self.den
        den = self.den * other.den
        common = self.gcf(num,den)
        return Fraction(num/common , den/common)

    def __iadd__(self,other):
        self.num = self.num * other.den + other.num * self.den
        self.den = self.den * other.den
        common = self.gcf(self.num,self.den)
        self.num = self.num/common
        self.den = self.den/common
```

Comment: always subclass from `object` if you are using Python 2.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `return self` at the end of your `__iadd__` implementation. Augmented assignment methods are allowed to return different instances, which is why `return self` is necessary.

In an unrelated note, you can reduce some code duplication by implementing addition in terms of in-place addition, like this:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    clone = Fraction(self.num, self.den)
    clone += other
    return clone
```

Comment: Actually after looking at my code I realized that I did that on purpose; if you use += it doesn't return a number.

Comment: @william880513 That was likely the result of the bug explained in the first paragraph of my answer.

Comment: What I am trying to do is so that I can change the value of a fraction by doing fraction1 += fraction2, instead of fraction1.__iadd__(fraction2)

Comment: @william880513 ...and definining `__iadd__` will accomplish exactly that — provided you remember to `return self` at the end of it. The suggestion for how to avoid code duplication in `__add__` is just an aside.

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977179/python-magic-method-augmented-assignment-misunderstanding) This explain why return self is necessary